# Query Parse SDK joining two classes

Tags: iphone, ios, parse-platform

I'm using Parse.com in an iOS app.

I have two classes

- User
- Post

where a user has a boolean flag called 'blocked'.

I want to retrieve all posts of al non blocked users ( where blocked = 0 )

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What does the data you get look like?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming your Post class has a pointer to the User class in a "user" key, you can use a inner query:

```
PFQuery *nonBlockedUserInnerQuery = [PFUser query];
[nonBlockedUserInnerQuery whereKey:@"blocked" equalTo:@NO];

PFQuery *postsByNonBlockedUsersQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Post"]
[postsByNonBlockedUsersQuery whereKey:@"user" matchesQuery:nonBlockedUserInnerQuery];
[postsByNonBlockedUsersQuery findObjects...
```

Basically you're querying for Posts whose user pointer satisfies a query for non-blocked users.

Comment: Thanks this solution works. But if i have more than a 1000 user then the first query won't return all the users which will make the second query return only posts from the 1000 users! Is there a way to overcome this?